# jquery and highslide

Tags: jquery

I use this js http://highslide.com.
I have a separate div and i want open the highslide with this div with onclick event..
I have try this but not work..

```
$('#po').click(function(){ 
var s = $('#ap_1');
return hs.expand(s, config1);
});
```

`#ap_1` is the first a tag element ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `hs.expand` takes a DOM element; try using `hs.expand(s.get(0), config1);`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('a.highslide').click(function() {
    return hs.expand(this, options);
});
```